# Buscar palabras con más de 7 letras en una sopa

Tags: c, string, matrices

estoy programando un programa que resuelva sopas de letras, indicándole tú la palabra que quieres buscar. El problema que tengo, es que no consigo que busque palabras con siete letras o más. Por el momento solo busca palabras en horizontal.

Se que el fallo está en la función **buscarPalabra**, o al menos eso creo. Y para facilitar las cosas se pueden meter varias palabras para buscar separándolas con espacios de esta forma "rosa belgica alemania" (esas palabras están pero no muestra la última).

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ENTER '\n'

void recogerLetras(int ancho, int alto, char letras[ancho*alto]);
void rellenarMatriz(int i, int j, char matriz[i][j], char elementos[i*j]);
void mostrarMatriz(int i, int j, char matriz[i][j]);
void buscarPalabra(int i, int j, char matriz[i][j], int longitud,  char palabra[longitud]);

typedef char* pChar;

int main() {
    int ancho = 30, alto = 30;

    printf("\nEscribe el ancho y el alto de la sopa de letras: ");
   // scanf("%d %d", &ancho, &alto);
    char letras[ancho*alto];
    pChar palabra = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char sopa[ancho-1][alto-1]; //Crea una matriz con el tamano real que tendra la sopa

    //recogerLetras(ancho, alto, letras); //Recoge las letras de la sopa en un array unidimensional

    rellenarMatriz(ancho, alto, sopa, "lakngmargnehfxwnoduaaaahoiuzuuujkaaznxgelioeacsbelgicaimyngeblkntjoluaniimrjunafxoxdlwawvguoiunzqytaoorqmdvcialrvueajicmhjowdzaruewjbajburnqzpelebgnbsbjnluauflevsbfeyaksmemnpiyumihlufylueikjagucxaubarifheinwnxynjkhcihghenkupcmenucoihzenspuqudrxgcrjrbajnaranlnrreozkookaotfqssdualiatsaiuufnuganhvulovueavrgruamgsigwqzaycaeviaaoyddoeyabuanavabquaarwhwunrucuqjauuaunnocnpouemecrosasunvwynpxrpaquvuoifndbcutsenjqjramutuaeoqtpyeehucfdncobvgnqagjqtahebrmvmipocgkvjeyqayfdazraocikmxmaftawnuufoirnilyyaruprupljnaapizfprtajdkeytbjznnopofuajsrrdxneenctgidatalemaniaaawnpcslratempkguvncangeuevjemsldcoipaooqkienphvohiapgpnivsioizufljgnwofnhqxjdcpfmojorpesaaenqrfuupnmchaojqfmhskfeiihinnaxdnbuntesufuciukuuioziyuiiizoiphxinursifoeixusnrwuurmlqtuinxssiscaognfejsznaeruouwcnnglijisarttepiacpjxujmiruovzkezeuanopjbmdaiizofoqohbyzasuvghqoppuajyiruuozwvuptaxvupucyrqleozgwslbetuixropugomwtiozjasitnvzpicqvienmwdyukinn"); //Las letras recogidas antes, se transforman en una matriz bidimensional
    mostrarMatriz(ancho, alto, sopa); //Muestra la matriz con el formato de una sopa de letras

    printf("\nEscribe todas las palabras que deseas buscar separadas por espacios: ");
    do {
        scanf("%s", palabra);
        buscarPalabra(ancho, alto, sopa, (int) strlen(palabra), palabra);
    } while(getchar() != ENTER);

    return 0;
}

void recogerLetras(int ancho, int alto, char letras[ancho*alto]) {
    int iterador = 0;
    printf("\nEscribe todas las letras seguidas y sin espacios: ");
    do {
        scanf("%s", letras);   //Guarda las letras en un array
        iterador++;
    } while(getchar() != ENTER); // El bucle para cuando entra un ENTER

}

void rellenarMatriz(int i, int j, char matriz[i][j], char elementos[i*j]) {
    int indiceElementos = 0;

    printf("\n");
    for(int fila = 0;  fila < j; fila++) {
        for(int columna = 0; columna < i; columna++) {
            matriz[columna][fila] = elementos[indiceElementos];
            printf("%c ", matriz[columna][fila]);
            indiceElementos++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}

void mostrarMatriz(int i, int j, char matriz[i][j]) {
    printf("\n\n");

    for (int fila = 0; fila < j; fila++) {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < i; columna++) {
            printf("%c  ", matriz[columna][fila]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void buscarPalabra(int i, int j, char matriz[i][j], int longitud, char palabra[longitud]) {

    int fila = 0, columna = 0;
    pChar posiblePalabra = malloc(sizeof(char));
     do {
        do {
            //printf("\nEstoy fila %d y columna %d", fila, columna);
            if(palabra[0] == matriz[columna][fila]) {
                //printf("\nEstoy en IF en fila %d y columna %d, palabra[%d] %c matriz[%d][%d] %c\n", fila, columna, 0, palabra[0], columna, fila, matriz[columna][fila]);
                for(int longitudPalabra = 0; longitudPalabra < longitud; longitudPalabra++) {
                    posiblePalabra[longitudPalabra] = matriz[columna+longitudPalabra][fila];
                    //printf("%c", posiblePalabra[longitudPalabra]);
                }
            }
            if(strcmp(posiblePalabra, palabra)==0) {
                break;
            }

            columna++;
        } while(columna < i);
         if(strcmp(posiblePalabra, palabra)==0) {
             break;
         }
        columna = 0;
        fila++;
    } while(fila < j);

     if(strcmp(posiblePalabra, palabra)==0) {
         printf("\nSe encontro la palabra \"%s\" en fila %d y columna %d", palabra, fila+1, columna+1);
     } else {
         printf("\nNo se encontro la palabra \"%s\" en ninguna linea horizontal", palabra);
     }





}

//2 2 abcd
//3 3 abcdefghi
//4 4 abcdefghijklmno
//5 5 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
//10 10 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
//15 15 aholafrojoklmnopqrstuazulabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstadios
```

Comment: Escribir tanto confunde al lector, te recomiendo que solo pongas lo que se necesario para que tu problema se entienda bien

Comment: Lo corrijo ahora, muchas gracias

Comment: He compilado tu código de github y veo que no está ni la palabra BELGICA ni ALEMANIA en tu sopa, por lo que está bien que te diga que no existe. He ido más allá, a la raíz de tu problema y he metido la palabra `abcdefghij`, la cual tiene más de 7 palabras, y te la encuentra perfectamente. ¿No será que tu código funciona correctamente pero que estás intentando buscar una palabra que no existe pero tú crees que la has metido?

Comment: Hola @Londo, tenía desactualizado el repositorio de GitHub. Ya lo actualicé y ya está bien puesta la sopa de letras correcta con las palabras que dije anteriormente. Muchas gracias y disculpa las molestias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras mucho buscar no encontré cual era el problema, por lo que finalmente decidí una forma distinta para buscar palabras. Así que cambiando el sistema de búsqueda utilizando booleanos cuando las letras coinciden se solucionó todo. El código de la función de búsqueda quedó de esta manera.

```c
bool buscarPalabraHorizontalDerecha(int i, int j, char matriz[i][j], int longitud, char palabra[longitud]) {
    int fila = 0, columna = 0;
    bool letrasCoincidentes = false;

    do {
        do {
            if(palabra[0] == matriz[columna][fila]) {
               for(int longitudPalabra = 0; longitudPalabra < longitud; longitudPalabra++) {
                    if(palabra[longitudPalabra] == matriz[columna+longitudPalabra][fila]) {
                        letrasCoincidentes = true;
                    } else {
                        letrasCoincidentes = false;
                        break;
                    }
               }

            }
            if(letrasCoincidentes == true) break;

            columna++;
        } while(columna < i);
        if(letrasCoincidentes == true) break;

        columna = 0;
        fila++;
    } while(fila < j);

    if(letrasCoincidentes == true) {
        printf("\nSe encontro la palabra \"%s\" en\tFILA:%d COLUMNA:%d\t en posicion HORIZONTAL DERECHA", palabra, fila+1, columna+1);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```